# `cond` with less redundancy

Tags: elisp, conditionals

Is there a better way to write the below code with less redundancy?

```
(cond
((firstFunction str1) (secondFunction str1))
((firstFunction str2) (secondFunction str2))
((firstFunction str3) (secondFunction str3))
((firstFunction str4) (secondFunction str4))
((firstFunction str5) (secondFunction str5))
)
```

Answer (score 10):

Traditional Emacs Lisp "in my time we didn't have that new-fangled CL stuff" style:

```
(catch 'foo
    (dolist (str (list str1 str2 str3 str4))
       (if (firstFunction str)
           (throw 'foo (secondFunction str))))
```

Traditional Emacs Lisp "when I was at MIT..." style:

```
(catch 'foo
    (mapc #'(lambda (str)
              (if (firstFunction str)
                  (throw 'foo (secondFunction str))))
        (list str1 str2 str3 str4)))
```

Traditional Emacs Lisp "and now get off my lawn" style:

```
(let ((list (list str1 str2 str4)))
   (catch 'foo
       (while list
           (let ((str (pop list)))
               (if (firstFunction str)
                   (throw 'foo (secondFunction str)))))))
```

Answer (score 8):

Wouldn't a loop do it?

```
(cl-dolist (str (list str1 str2 str3 ...))
  (when (first-function str)
    (cl-return (second-function str))))
```

Comment: No, @JosephGarvin, the `cl-return` breaks out of the loop.

Comment: Oh, read too fast, you are correct.

Answer (score 8):

Another way using `dash.el`. You could also do this with `cl-lib` functions.

```
(-when-let (found (-find 'firstFunction (list str1 str2 str3 str3)))
  (secondFunction found))
```

Or, if you know at least one condition will always match:

```
(secondFunction (-find 'firstFunction (list str1 str2 str3 str3)))
```

Comment: Why use dash over `cl-lib`?

Comment: Honestly I use it so I can type `filter` instead of `cl-remove-if-not`.

Comment: The problem with dash is that by using it you exclude everyone who's more familiar with Emacs Lisp and CL than dash... and that's a lot of people.  The fairly minor improvements brought by dash don't justify the cultural incompatibility.

Comment: I think it goes both ways, by using cl-lib you exclude everyone more familiar with most currently popular language than emacs lisp. Any one coming from a language like js, ruby, clojure, and others will immediately understand what a `-filter` function does and will probably scratch their heads at something so unfortunately named as `cl-remove-if-not`.

Answer (score 4):

Just for fun...

```
(funcall (lambda (f l) (funcall f l f))
         (lambda (l f) (if l (if (firstFunction (car l))
                                 (secondFunction (car l))
                                 (funcall f (cdr l) f))))
         (list str1 str2 str3 str4 str5))
```

Or, without lambda tricks:

```
(defun superCond (l) (if l (if (firstFunction (car l))
                               (secondFunction (car l))
                               (superCond (cdr l)))))
(superCond (list str1 str2 str3 str4 str5))
```

Or:

```
(defun superCond (l f1 f2)
  (if l
    (if (funcall f1 (car l))
        (funcall f2 (car l))
        (superCond (cdr l) f1 f2))))
(superCond (list str1 str2 str3 str4 str5) #'firstFunction #'secondFunction)
```

Answer (score 1):

One more. Make sure to have `pp-macroexpand-last-sexp` at hand.

```el
(cl-macrolet ((find-and-use-str (ff sf &rest strs)
                                (cons 'cond
                                      (mapcar (lambda (str)
                                                `((,ff ,str) (,sf ,str)))
                                              strs))))
  (find-and-use-str firstFunc secondFunc "foo" "bar" "baz"))
```

Please note that the elements of `strs` will be evaluated twice. In the example, it's ok because they're constant (strings).

Answer (score 1):

Another answer, unlike to others this doesn't rely on fancy libraries and esoteric features like `catch` and `throw`:

```
(let ((rest (list str1 str2 str3 str4 str5)))
  (while rest
    (let ((entry (pop rest)))
      (when (firstFunction entry)
        (secondFunction entry)
        (setq rest ())))))
```

This assumes that the value the original `cond` expression wasn't used.

Comment: `catch`/`throw` is esoteric?

Answer (score 1):

This macro does the trick.

```
(defmacro condstrings (f1 f2 &rest strings)
  `(cond ,@(mapcar (lambda (s)
                     `((,f1 ,s) (,f2 ,s)))
                   strings)))

(condstrings firstFunction secondFunction str1 str2 str3 str4 str5)
```

If it's a concern that the strings are each evaluated twice then you can use the `once-only` macro defined [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/macro-utils.el)